# Artifactory won't copy npm modules

Tags: npm, artifactory

I'm trying to install npm modules into a local repository which fetches outside npm modules using artifactory. Any npm module which begins with an at symbol (@) results in an error 404

```
npm install -D @easy-webpack/core
npm ERR! Windows NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! node v4.2.4
npm ERR! npm v3.10.5
npm ERR! 400 bad request
```

Is there anything I can do in the artifactory configuration to fix this problem?

This seems to be happening on any npm module which begins with a special symbol like @

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol `@` in an npm package's name signifies it's a [scoped package](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope) - You have to specifically [configure](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry#NpmRegistry-ConfiguringthenpmClientforaScopeRegistry) your client to work with Artifactory as a scope registry.

Comment: Seems that the version of Artifactory that I was using was out of date. An update to version 4.3x seems to have solved this issue.